# Why is SVGator's animated svg not displaying properly on Chrome?

Tags: css, animation, svg

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhUe6.png)I used SVGator to create a simple animation so I can use it on my website. The animation shows perfectly fine in the editor. However, when I export it and view it from my browser (Chrome 67 / Windows 10) or from my website, few elements skip their animation and weirdly jump straight to their end state.

Here's a link to the SVG: http://jmp.sh/2DOfAD2

P.S I am no expert at coding so I can't really figure out what's wrong with it by looking at the lines of code. But here is the [link to the code for you](http://jmp.sh/v/nWwnoNgPldCbr5sAHQNV)

And an excerpt of the code:

```
    </style>
<g id="B1xEEHH6bm" display="none">
</g>
<g id="S1-EErHpW7">
    <g id="rkfVNrr6-m">
        <g id="r17VVSS6bm">
            <path d="M116.998,343.135" id="ByENEBBaZX"/>
            <path d="M116.998,343.135" id="BkHNNBHpZQ"/>
        </g>
    </g>
    <g id="Sk8VVrBTbm">
        <g id="HJDV4rSpbQ">
            <g id="H1dNESHa-m">
                <polygon points="103.563,307.839 83.113,319.964 83.113,294.62 103.563,282.52 &#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;" id="SkKVEBBTbm"/>
                <polygon points="83.113,319.964 43.361,307.29 43.361,281.939 83.113,294.62 &#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;" id="S1qNESr6WQ"/>
                <polygon points="83.113,294.62 43.361,281.939 63.813,269.84 103.563,282.52 &#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;" id="r1o4VBBpbX"/>
            </g>
            <g id="SyhN4HH6WX">
                <rect x="52.305" y="278.46" width="11.608" height="3.49" id="r1TV4SSpZm"/>
                <g id="BJCN4rrabX">
                    <ellipse cx="58.109" cy="281.95" rx="5.804" ry="2.604" id="Hy1g44BHpZQ"/>
                    <ellipse cx="58.109" cy="278.46" rx="5.804" ry="2.604" id="S1ee4VBHTbm"/>
                </g>
            </g>
            <g id="rJ-g4NSSa-m">
                <rect x="62.747" y="271.93" width="11.608" height="3.49" id="r1MxNNBraW7"/>
                <g id="B1XxNVHHTbm">
                    <ellipse cx="68.551" cy="275.42" rx="5.804" ry="2.605" id="S1NxVNrSp-7"/>
                    <ellipse cx="68.551" cy="271.93" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="SJHlV4BB6bQ"/>
                </g>
            </g>
            <g id="BJUg4NHHT-Q">
                <rect x="73.521" y="285.398" width="11.608" height="3.49" id="ryDgNErB6-m"/>
                <g id="SkOgEVBrTWX">
                    <ellipse cx="79.325" cy="288.889" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="ByKe4VrH6-7"/>
                    <ellipse cx="79.325" cy="285.398" rx="5.804" ry="2.605" id="ryqlN4rHa-m"/>
                </g>
            </g>
            <g id="r1sx44rHT-m">
                <rect x="83.581" y="279.32" width="11.608" height="3.49" id="S1nl4NHHpZm"/>
                <g id="ryTx4Nrr6WQ">
                    <ellipse cx="89.385" cy="282.811" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="r1CgENHBaWm"/>
                    <ellipse cx="89.385" cy="279.32" rx="5.804" ry="2.605" id="HJkZVNHBa-X"/>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
        <g id="r1gbN4SBa-7">
            <g id="Bk-Z44SrTZm">
                <polygon points="143.315,320.533 122.864,332.658 122.864,307.313 143.315,295.213 &#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;" id="Skzb4NBHaWX"/>
                <polygon points="122.864,332.658 83.113,319.983 83.113,294.635 122.864,307.313 &#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;" id="BJQ-4NHS6-Q"/>
                <polygon points="122.864,307.313 83.113,294.635 103.564,282.534 143.315,295.213 &#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;" id="HyE-V4HS6Wm"/>
            </g>
            <g id="ByrZE4SrpZX">
                <rect x="92.056" y="291.152" width="11.608" height="3.49" id="rkIZNVBS6-X"/>
                <g id="ryDW4EBrpZ7">
                    <ellipse cx="97.86" cy="294.644" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="S1_ZEEHSab7"/>
                    <ellipse cx="97.86" cy="291.153" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="BJK-N4SrTbQ"/>
                </g>
            </g>
            <g id="Hy9-4NSr6bQ">
                <rect x="102.499" y="284.624" width="11.608" height="3.489" id="HJjZNVBr6ZX"/>
                <g id="Sy2WNESrpWX">
                    <ellipse cx="108.303" cy="288.114" rx="5.804" ry="2.605" id="SJaZNESHaZQ"/>
                    <ellipse cx="108.303" cy="284.624" rx="5.804" ry="2.604" id="HJ0ZVEHrTZX"/>
                </g>
            </g>
            <g id="HkyfEVrBTZQ">
                <rect x="113.272" y="298.092" width="11.608" height="3.491" id="HJezNNHHp-X"/>
                <g id="H1ZGE4HSTZQ">
                    <ellipse cx="119.076" cy="301.583" rx="5.804" ry="2.604" id="SJzf4NBr6bX"/>
                    <ellipse cx="119.076" cy="298.092" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="S1mz4NSHaWX"/>
                </g>
            </g>
            <g id="BkVf4Vrr6Wm">
                <rect x="123.332" y="292.014" width="11.608" height="3.491" id="BySfV4rSTZQ"/>
                <g id="B1IM44HS6-X">
                    <ellipse cx="129.136" cy="295.505" rx="5.804" ry="2.604" id="HkPG44BrTWm"/>
                    <ellipse cx="129.136" cy="292.014" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="S1OGENBSpWX"/>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
        <g id="BJKfVErSaZ7_B1XM8SpZm" data-animator-group="true" data-animator-type="0">
            <g id="BJKfVErSaZ7">
                <g id="HkcGNEHBTb7">
                    <polygon points="123.024,288.641 102.574,300.766 102.574,275.42 123.024,263.318 &#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;" id="BJjf4ESrT-X"/>
                    <polygon points="102.574,300.766 62.822,288.09 62.822,262.741 102.574,275.42 &#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;" id="B12MNVHB6b7"/>
                    <polygon points="102.574,275.42 62.822,262.741 83.274,250.641 123.024,263.318 &#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;" id="rkpfNNrHT-Q"/>
                </g>
                <g id="ByRzE4SH6bm">
                    <rect x="71.766" y="259.26" width="11.608" height="3.49" id="BkyXVVrr6WQ"/>
                    <g id="BJlmNEHSa-X">
                        <ellipse cx="77.57" cy="262.75" rx="5.804" ry="2.605" id="SkZQEEHHa-7"/>
                        <ellipse cx="77.57" cy="259.26" rx="5.804" ry="2.605" id="BJfQ4NBSa-m"/>
                    </g>
                </g>
                <g id="By7XE4SH6-7">
                    <rect x="82.208" y="252.73" width="11.608" height="3.49" id="ByNm4VBS6WX"/>
                    <g id="SkBmVESH6-7">
                        <ellipse cx="88.012" cy="256.221" rx="5.804" ry="2.605" id="r1IXENrSaZm"/>
                        <ellipse cx="88.012" cy="252.73" rx="5.804" ry="2.605" id="S1v744HHTWX"/>
                    </g>
                </g>
                <g id="SydXE4BSa-7">
                    <rect x="92.981" y="266.198" width="11.608" height="3.491" id="r1Km44rS6Zm"/>
                    <g id="Sk97VVHHa-X">
                        <ellipse cx="98.786" cy="269.689" rx="5.804" ry="2.605" id="SyjQ4NrHTb7"/>
                        <ellipse cx="98.786" cy="266.198" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="S13XN4BHab7"/>
                    </g>
                </g>
                <g id="B1a74EBB6bm">
                    <rect x="103.042" y="260.12" width="11.608" height="3.491" id="BJR7V4rr6WX"/>
                    <g id="rk1VVEBrpbQ">
                        <ellipse cx="108.846" cy="263.611" rx="5.804" ry="2.605" id="rkeN44HrTWQ"/>
                        <ellipse cx="108.846" cy="260.12" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="r1ZE4NHH6W7"/>
                    </g>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
        <g id="BkGVNVSB6-Q_rJYXOUH6-X" data-animator-group="true" data-animator-type="0">
            <g id="BkGVNVSB6-Q">
                <g id="HJQNV4Hra-7">
                    <polygon points="123.024,263.714 102.574,275.839 102.574,250.495 123.024,238.394 &#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;" id="B1VNN4rH6-Q"/>
                    <polygon points="102.574,275.839 62.822,263.164 62.822,237.815 102.574,250.495 &#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;" id="HJBNE4SrpZm"/>
                    <polygon points="102.574,250.495 62.822,237.815 83.274,225.715 123.024,238.394 &#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;" id="SJLEV4BBaZ7"/>
                </g>
                <g id="ByDVVEBHTWX">
                    <rect x="71.766" y="234.334" width="11.608" height="3.491" id="HJ_N4VSHpWX"/>
                    <g id="BJKNNVrrT-m">
                        <ellipse cx="77.57" cy="237.825" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="BJ5ENEHrT-X"/>
                        <ellipse cx="77.57" cy="234.334" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="SkjNNESSab7"/>
                    </g>
                </g>
                <g id="SJhE4NSS6bQ">
                    <rect x="82.208" y="227.805" width="11.608" height="3.49" id="r1T44VHS6bm"/>
                    <g id="SyRN44HHTWQ">
                        <ellipse cx="88.012" cy="231.295" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="BJkrNVSHT-m"/>
                        <ellipse cx="88.012" cy="227.805" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="S1eBEVSS6bX"/>
                    </g>
                </g>
                <g id="rkbrNVHr6b7">
                    <rect x="92.981" y="241.273" width="11.608" height="3.491" id="SJGrVVSH6-X"/>
                    <g id="BJXrNVrHpbQ">
                        <ellipse cx="98.786" cy="244.764" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="r1VHVVrSabX"/>
                        <ellipse cx="98.786" cy="241.273" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="HkrrENBrpbm"/>
                    </g>
                </g>
                <g id="ByIHE4HS6-7">
                    <rect x="103.042" y="235.195" width="11.608" height="3.491" id="BJPHV4rHTbX"/>
                    <g id="BJ_BEErrT-X">
                        <ellipse cx="108.846" cy="238.686" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="r1YHENrBpbQ"/>
                        <ellipse cx="108.846" cy="235.195" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="SJ9SN4Sr6Wm"/>
                    </g>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
        <g id="SysBVNBBTZm_SJpBwST-X" data-animator-group="true" data-animator-type="0">
            <g id="SysBVNBBTZm">
                <g id="HknB44HSaWX">
                    <polygon points="123.054,238.428 102.603,250.553 102.603,225.208 123.054,213.108 &#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;" id="SkTrEVSHTWm"/>
                    <polygon points="102.603,250.553 62.852,237.878 62.852,212.529 102.603,225.208 &#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;" id="SJCSVEBrp-Q"/>
                    <polygon points="102.603,225.208 62.852,212.529 83.303,200.429 123.054,213.108 &#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;" id="r11LVESHpb7"/>
                </g>
                <g id="ryeINNHrTZm">
                    <rect x="71.795" y="209.048" width="11.608" height="3.491" id="Bkb8EVrSpb7"/>
                    <g id="Byz8N4SHpZm">
                        <ellipse cx="77.599" cy="212.539" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="SkXLVNHHTWX"/>
                        <ellipse cx="77.599" cy="209.048" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="BkEL44BraWX"/>
                    </g>
                </g>
                <g id="rkHLEVSSa-7">
                    <rect x="82.237" y="202.519" width="11.608" height="3.49" id="BkIUN4BH6Z7"/>
                    <g id="BJPLV4rST-m">
                        <ellipse cx="88.042" cy="206.009" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="r1dIVEBr6ZX"/>
                        <ellipse cx="88.042" cy="202.519" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="ryt8V4Br6WX"/>
                    </g>
                </g>
                <g id="rJ9UE4HH6-7">
                    <rect x="93.011" y="215.987" width="11.608" height="3.491" id="BkiIVNBSaZQ"/>
                    <g id="Sy2UVVBHTZQ">
                        <ellipse cx="98.815" cy="219.478" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="rk6LNVBBaW7"/>
                        <ellipse cx="98.815" cy="215.987" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="r1RLVVrBT-m"/>
                    </g>
                </g>
                <g id="HJyvVNBH6ZQ">
                    <rect x="103.071" y="209.909" width="11.608" height="3.491" id="rklvNEBSab7"/>
                    <g id="By-P44rH6-m">
                        <ellipse cx="108.875" cy="213.399" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="HyGvEESBT-7"/>
                        <ellipse cx="108.875" cy="209.909" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="r17vEVrSTbX"/>
                    </g>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
        <g id="H1Ew4NBra-m_HJ8twBa-X" data-animator-group="true" data-animator-type="0">
            <g id="H1Ew4NBra-m">
                <g id="B1HwNVSrp-Q">
                    <polygon points="123.112,213.108 102.661,225.232 102.661,199.889 123.112,187.788 &#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;" id="HyIDE4HBaZQ"/>
                    <polygon points="102.661,225.232 62.91,212.558 62.91,187.209 102.661,199.889 &#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;" id="SywD4NHHT-m"/>
                    <polygon points="102.661,199.889 62.91,187.209 83.361,175.108 123.112,187.788 &#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;" id="B1uvNNHHaZX"/>
                </g>
                <g id="r1KPV4rB6bX">
                    <rect x="71.854" y="183.728" width="11.608" height="3.491" id="SycDE4rB6ZX"/>
                    <g id="HyoDENSrT-Q">
                        <ellipse cx="77.658" cy="187.219" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="Synv4VrBTb7"/>
                        <ellipse cx="77.658" cy="183.728" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="r1aDVEBr6bm"/>
                    </g>
                </g>
                <g id="rkRPE4SH6WX">
                    <rect x="82.296" y="177.199" width="11.608" height="3.49" id="H1k_N4SrpWm"/>
                    <g id="Hyg_E4HraZ7">
                        <ellipse cx="88.1" cy="180.689" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="BJbOE4SB6-Q"/>
                        <ellipse cx="88.1" cy="177.199" rx="5.804" ry="2.605" id="S1GuENrST-7"/>
                    </g>
                </g>
                <g id="S1XuNEHra-7">
                    <rect x="93.069" y="190.667" width="11.608" height="3.491" id="HJ4_4VSraZQ"/>
                    <g id="HySdNErHTb7">
                        <ellipse cx="98.874" cy="194.158" rx="5.804" ry="2.605" id="BJIuN4Hrp-Q"/>
                        <ellipse cx="98.874" cy="190.667" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="H1DuNErH6bQ"/>
                    </g>
                </g>
                <g id="Hy__44rHaWm">
                    <rect x="103.129" y="184.589" width="11.608" height="3.49" id="SyYO4EHSTbX"/>
                    <g id="Hy5d4NHBT-Q">
                        <ellipse cx="108.933" cy="188.079" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="HkidEEHSaWQ"/>
                        <ellipse cx="108.933" cy="184.589" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="BJ2dN4HSa-7"/>
                    </g>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
        <g id="BJpuNEBHpZQ_SJ43PH6W7" data-animator-group="true" data-animator-type="0">
            <g id="BJpuNEBHpZQ">
                <g id="BJRuV4BH6b7">
                    <polygon points="123.112,187.754 102.661,199.879 102.661,174.535 123.112,162.434 &#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;" id="ByJKENBST-X"/>
                    <polygon points="102.661,199.879 62.91,187.204 62.91,161.855 102.661,174.535 &#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;" id="BJeYVVSHa-Q"/>
                    <polygon points="102.661,174.535 62.91,161.855 83.361,149.755 123.112,162.434 &#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;" id="BkWtVVHBTbQ"/>
                </g>
                <g id="B1Mt4VHra-7">
                    <rect x="71.854" y="158.374" width="11.608" height="3.491" id="r17K4VrS6-7"/>
                    <g id="B1EKEVBBTbX">
                        <ellipse cx="77.658" cy="161.865" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="ryrFNNSr6Z7"/>
                        <ellipse cx="77.658" cy="158.374" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="HJItV4Hra-X"/>
                    </g>
                </g>
                <g id="HywFV4BBTZX">
                    <rect x="82.296" y="151.845" width="11.608" height="3.49" id="SkutENSS6Z7"/>
                    <g id="HyFt4VBBpZ7">
                        <ellipse cx="88.1" cy="155.335" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="BycFV4BHaZ7"/>
                        <ellipse cx="88.1" cy="151.845" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="HyitN4rHpZQ"/>
                    </g>
                </g>
                <g id="S1ntN4HSpZ7">
                    <rect x="93.069" y="165.313" width="11.608" height="3.491" id="BJTKVVrHTZQ"/>
                    <g id="BJ0tEErSpbX">
                        <ellipse cx="98.874" cy="168.804" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="Hkyq44BSabm"/>
                        <ellipse cx="98.874" cy="165.313" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="H1gqNNBS6W7"/>
                    </g>
                </g>
                <g id="Sk-qN4SHab7">
                    <rect x="103.129" y="159.235" width="11.608" height="3.491" id="HkzcENSSp-Q"/>
                    <g id="HkQc4VSr6-Q">
                        <ellipse cx="108.933" cy="162.726" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="BJV5VNHBp-7"/>
                        <ellipse cx="108.933" cy="159.235" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="HJH5EEBST-Q"/>
                    </g>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
        <g id="ByUcENHSpZ7_SkYkdHT-7" data-animator-group="true" data-animator-type="0">
            <g id="ByUcENHSpZ7">
                <g id="rJDqVNHr6WX">
                    <polygon points="123.112,162.434 102.661,174.559 102.661,149.215 123.112,137.114 &#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;" id="ryu5VEHSTbX"/>
                    <polygon points="102.661,174.559 62.91,161.884 62.91,136.536 102.661,149.215 &#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;" id="BkF9V4BHabm"/>
                    <polygon points="102.661,149.215 62.91,136.536 83.361,124.435 123.112,137.114 &#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;" id="ry594VBBpWX"/>
                </g>
                <g id="B1sqN4rHTWX">
                    <rect x="71.854" y="133.054" width="11.608" height="3.491" id="B12q44BraZX"/>
                    <g id="SJTqVVHHTbX">
                        <ellipse cx="77.658" cy="136.545" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="BkRcNVrBTbm"/>
                        <ellipse cx="77.658" cy="133.054" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="ryyiVErrpbQ"/>
                    </g>
                </g>
                <g id="SklsVNSHTb7">
                    <rect x="82.296" y="126.524" width="11.608" height="3.491" id="r1-s44rrT-X"/>
                    <g id="Syfj44SHT-Q">
                        <ellipse cx="88.1" cy="130.015" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="r1XsENHHp-m"/>
                        <ellipse cx="88.1" cy="126.524" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="Hy4oE4BHT-7"/>
                    </g>
                </g>
                <g id="H1BoN4HB6W7">
                    <rect x="93.069" y="139.993" width="11.608" height="3.49" id="rk8oENrST-m"/>
                    <g id="SyDsV4rrpW7">
                        <ellipse cx="98.874" cy="143.483" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="r1_jV4rSpZ7"/>
                        <ellipse cx="98.874" cy="139.993" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="SJKoEESr6b7"/>
                    </g>
                </g>
                <g id="Skci4EHBp-m">
                    <rect x="103.129" y="133.915" width="11.608" height="3.49" id="rkoi44HBTZm"/>
                    <g id="rynsV4HSTZ7">
                        <ellipse cx="108.933" cy="137.405" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="Byps4VrSaZ7"/>
                        <ellipse cx="108.933" cy="133.915" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="SkCjNEBST-7"/>
                    </g>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
        <g id="HkJ3NVrB6-m_Hy4fuHTb7" data-animator-group="true" data-animator-type="0">
            <g id="HkJ3NVrB6-m">
                <g id="SJg244BraW7">
                    <polygon points="105,131.264 84.549,143.389 84.549,118.044 105,105.944 &#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;" id="B1WhE4rSaW7"/>
                    <polygon points="84.549,143.389 44.797,130.714 44.797,105.366 84.549,118.044 &#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;" id="BJzn4VHrp-7"/>
                    <polygon points="84.549,118.044 44.797,105.366 65.249,93.265 105,105.944 &#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;" id="BJX2V4HBTbQ"/>
                </g>
                <g id="SyN3NESrabX">
                    <rect x="53.741" y="101.884" width="11.608" height="3.49" id="SkrhVNBraZQ"/>
                    <g id="Bk824NSS6b7">
                        <ellipse cx="59.545" cy="105.375" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="S1wnNVrrT-X"/>
                        <ellipse cx="59.545" cy="101.884" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="r1u3NVSHTZX"/>
                    </g>
                </g>
                <g id="ryY3NESHpWm">
                    <rect x="64.183" y="95.354" width="11.608" height="3.491" id="H1c3VVBSaZX"/>
                    <g id="HJihNEBBT-X">
                        <ellipse cx="69.987" cy="98.845" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="rJn24VSSTb7"/>
                        <ellipse cx="69.987" cy="95.354" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="Hka3EEBrpWm"/>
                    </g>
                </g>
                <g id="rJR3VESB6Z7">
                    <rect x="74.957" y="108.823" width="11.608" height="3.49" id="BJyaVNrSaW7"/>
                    <g id="SkgTNNrB6WX">
                        <ellipse cx="80.761" cy="112.313" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="Sy-aNNHH6-Q"/>
                        <ellipse cx="80.761" cy="108.823" rx="5.804" ry="2.605" id="SkzpNNSH6ZX"/>
                    </g>
                </g>
                <g id="S1mp4NHHTbX">
                    <rect x="85.017" y="102.745" width="11.608" height="3.491" id="HyEa44Hr6ZX"/>
                    <g id="SJr6ENrSabX">
                        <ellipse cx="90.821" cy="106.235" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="S1UaNNBSp-X"/>
                        <ellipse cx="90.821" cy="102.745" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="HJv6N4BH6WX"/>
                    </g>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
        <g id="Hy_6VVSBaZX_SJWHuHaW7" data-animator-group="true" data-animator-type="0">
            <g id="Hy_6VVSBaZX">
                <g id="ByK6VNrSTWm">
                    <polygon points="144.897,143.981 124.446,156.106 124.446,130.762 144.897,118.662 &#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;" id="S1564ErSpb7"/>
                    <polygon points="124.446,156.106 84.695,143.432 84.695,118.083 124.446,130.762 &#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;" id="Skj6NVrBTbm"/>
                    <polygon points="124.446,130.762 84.695,118.083 105.146,105.982 144.897,118.662 &#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;" id="Bk36ENSrpWX"/>
                </g>
                <g id="Skp6NVBBaW7">
                    <rect x="93.639" y="114.602" width="11.608" height="3.49" id="SkRaVNHSabQ"/>
                    <g id="SJk04VSSaZX">
                        <ellipse cx="99.443" cy="118.092" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="SklR4NHBTZm"/>
                        <ellipse cx="99.443" cy="114.602" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="H1WAE4SHp-X"/>
                    </g>
                </g>
                <g id="BkzA44BBTZX">
                    <rect x="104.081" y="108.072" width="11.608" height="3.491" id="ry7R4ESrTWm"/>
                    <g id="SyN0EEHrT-m">
                        <ellipse cx="109.885" cy="111.563" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="B1HC4NHB6Zm"/>
                        <ellipse cx="109.885" cy="108.072" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="r1LC4VSrabX"/>
                    </g>
                </g>
                <g id="H1vRVNSHa-7">
                    <rect x="114.854" y="121.541" width="11.608" height="3.49" id="rkuAV4SH6Zm"/>
                    <g id="S1YRVNHrpbQ">
                        <ellipse cx="120.658" cy="125.031" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="Sy5CNVrSaZ7"/>
                        <ellipse cx="120.658" cy="121.541" rx="5.804" ry="2.605" id="BkiCVVSrpZQ"/>
                    </g>
                </g>
                <g id="rk3RNVBr6WX">
                    <rect x="124.914" y="115.462" width="11.608" height="3.491" id="Bkp0VVSBTW7"/>
                    <g id="S10RV4rHab7">
                        <ellipse cx="130.718" cy="118.953" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="SJyyxE4rSTW7"/>
                        <ellipse cx="130.718" cy="115.462" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="B1gJxEESSabX"/>
                    </g>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
        <g id="SJ-1g44SrTZ7">
            <g id="SyMyxVErrpWQ">
                <polygon points="183.066,333.159 162.616,345.284 162.616,319.94 183.066,307.839 &#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;" id="ryQkl4VHSpWQ"/>
                <polygon points="162.616,345.284 122.864,332.609 122.864,307.261 162.616,319.94 &#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;" id="ryNyl44Hr6bm"/>
                <polygon points="162.616,319.94 122.864,307.261 143.316,295.16 183.066,307.839 &#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;" id="rJS1eV4Br6ZX"/>
            </g>
            <g id="rk81eNNHrpWX">
                <rect x="131.808" y="303.779" width="11.608" height="3.489" id="ByvJx4ESS6WX"/>
                <g id="H1dJe4ESr6ZX">
                    <ellipse cx="137.612" cy="307.27" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="HJFJeN4HHpZQ"/>
                    <ellipse cx="137.612" cy="303.779" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="ryqyxNNBrTW7"/>
                </g>
            </g>
            <g id="BksJeN4BS6bQ">
                <rect x="142.25" y="297.25" width="11.608" height="3.49" id="S131eNVHSTbm"/>
                <g id="Ska1gVErH6Zm">
                    <ellipse cx="148.054" cy="300.74" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="SyRkgEEHBa-m"/>
                    <ellipse cx="148.054" cy="297.25" rx="5.804" ry="2.605" id="S1kxx4NBBp-7"/>
                </g>
            </g>
            <g id="HkeeeN4HHpZm">
                <rect x="153.024" y="310.719" width="11.608" height="3.49" id="r1ZlgV4HSp-X"/>
                <g id="SyMgeENrBp-m">
                    <ellipse cx="158.828" cy="314.209" rx="5.804" ry="2.605" id="r1QllEEHBp-m"/>
                    <ellipse cx="158.828" cy="310.719" rx="5.804" ry="2.605" id="rkVxeVErr6bQ"/>
                </g>
            </g>
            <g id="ByrleVEBHTZQ">
                <rect x="163.083" y="304.641" width="11.608" height="3.49" id="S1UxgNNBHaWm"/>
                <g id="BkwleNNBBpb7">
                    <ellipse cx="168.888" cy="308.131" rx="5.804" ry="2.605" id="r1_egEEBrp-m"/>
                    <ellipse cx="168.888" cy="304.641" rx="5.804" ry="2.605" id="BkFlgENHS6b7"/>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
        <g id="Hy5glNNBBTb7_rJ-jdSaZm" data-animator-group="true" data-animator-type="0">
            <g id="Hy5glNNBBTb7">
                <g id="H1sexEVSrT-7">
                    <polygon points="166.624,126.052 146.173,138.177 146.173,112.833 166.624,100.732 &#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;" id="BynleNESHa-X"/>
                    <polygon points="146.173,138.177 106.421,125.502 106.421,100.154 146.173,112.833 &#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;" id="rypxe4NSBaWm"/>
                    <polygon points="146.173,112.833 106.421,100.154 126.873,88.053 166.624,100.732 &#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;" id="HkRxgNErHa-X"/>
                </g>
                <g id="H1JZg4NHH6bQ">
                    <rect x="115.365" y="96.672" width="11.608" height="3.49" id="rJgWlEVHrTb7"/>
                    <g id="SkbWlEEHBp-Q">
                        <ellipse cx="121.169" cy="100.163" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="ryz-xEEHBa-7"/>
                        <ellipse cx="121.169" cy="96.672" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="BJXZxEVBBpZm"/>
                    </g>
                </g>
                <g id="B14bgEEHSTbm">
                    <rect x="125.807" y="90.143" width="11.608" height="3.491" id="SkB-xEESSTW7"/>
                    <g id="By8blNVrBT-Q">
                        <ellipse cx="131.611" cy="93.633" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="HJPZxEESraZ7"/>
                        <ellipse cx="131.611" cy="90.143" rx="5.804" ry="2.606" id="r1_bgEVrH6WQ"/>
                    </g>
                </g>
                <g id="HJtZg4Erra-7">
                    <rect x="136.581" y="103.611" width="11.608" height="3.49" id="rJ5WxNESrTbX"/>
```

Comment: Rather than linking out to external sites, is it possible for you to [edit] the question and include both the code and the svg here? Doing so will lower the effort people will need to take to even glance at your question and it may increase the possibility of you getting a helpful answer.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I have added an excerpt of the code due to character count restraints and .png of the svg because svg is not supported apparently.

Comment: The animation http://jsfiddle.net/5m48fxL2/ works correctly in Firefox. So I can only assume it is a bug in Chrome.  [You should report it to them](https://crbug.com/wizard).

Comment: That's a bummer! I just installed firefox to check and it does work perfectly fine there. But how is it that other animations from SVGator and in other websites are working properly through Chrome?